# automate configuration of secpol.msc from powershell

Tags: security, powershell

How to get and set value in secpol.msc via powershell script

Local security policy-->Local Policies-->Security Options-->USer Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode

I need to get the orig value so I can return it back after changing it.

I need automatically set it to "elevate without prompting"

Answer (score 1):

A number of group policies are simply registry settings, including this one.

[User Account Control Group Policy and registry key settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/user-account-control-group-policy-and-registry-key-settings#registry-key-settings)

This particular policy is located in the registry at:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin`

And these are the possible values:

- 0 = Elevate without prompting
- 1 = Prompt for credentials on the secure desktop
- 2 = Prompt for consent on the secure desktop
- 3 = Prompt for credentials
- 4 = Prompt for consent
- 5 (Default) = Prompt for consent for non-Windows binaries

Using Powershell, you can get the value with something like this:

```
$result = Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System' -Name 'ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$result.ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin
```

Result: `5`

Then to set it:

```
Set-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System' -Name 'ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin' -Value 00000000
```